# Cannot add value of radio button

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.stars input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
        var radio1 = ( typeof $('.starRadio:checked').eq(0).val()  ==  'undefined' ) ? 0 : Number( $('.starRadio:checked').eq(0).val() );
        var radio2 = ( typeof $('.starRadio:checked').eq(1).val()  ==  'undefined' ) ? 0 : Number( $('.starRadio:checked').eq(1).val() );
        $('.output').html(radio1 + radio2)
    })
});
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Star Rating</title></head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<form>
<h2> Teacher 1: </h2>
<div class="stars">
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-1" id="star_a-1" value=1 />
        <label class="star-1" for="star_a-1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-2" id="star_a-2" value=2 />
        <label class="star-2" for="star_a-2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-3" id="star_a-3" value=3 />
        <label class="star-3" for="star_a-3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-4" id="star_a-4" value=4 />
        <label class="star-4" for="star_a-4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-5" id="star_a-5" value=5 />
        <label class="star-5" for="star_a-5">5</label>
        <span></span>
    </div>

<div class="stars">
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-1" id="star_b-1" value=1 />
        <label class="star-1" for="star_b-1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-2" id="star_b-2" value=2 />
        <label class="star-2" for="star_b-2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-3" id="star_b-3" value=3 />
        <label class="star-3" for="star_b-3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-4" id="star_b-4" value=4 />
        <label class="star-4" for="star_b-4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="star-5" id="star_b-5" value=5 />
        <label class="star-5" for="star_b-5">5</label>
        <span></span>
 </div>
     
<span id="sum"></span>
</form>
<script src="script.js">
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code that Im trying to execute. But Im not getting any results on the HTML code that i run on my browser. Im really confused. The code works perfectly fine on fiddle,  but i dunno why it's not working on my browser.

Comment: Yay, you used my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Have all radio have the same class so jQuery can easily select them
- all html attributes should have `''` or `""`
- and check that the values are defined else make them 0

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.stars input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
        var radio1 = ( typeof $('.starRadio:checked').eq(0).val()  ==  'undefined' ) ? 0 : Number( $('.starRadio:checked').eq(0).val() );
        var radio2 = ( typeof $('.starRadio:checked').eq(1).val()  ==  'undefined' ) ? 0 : Number( $('.starRadio:checked').eq(1).val() );
        $('.output').html(radio1 + radio2)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars">
    <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="starRadio star-1" id="star_a-1" value="1" />
    <label class="star-1" for="star_a-1">1</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="starRadio star-2" id="star_a-2" value="2"/>
    <label class="star-2" for="star_a-2">2</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="starRadio star-3" id="star_a-3" value="3"/>
    <label class="star-3" for="star_a-3">3</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="starRadio star-4" id="star_a-4" value="4"/>
    <label class="star-4" for="star_a-4">4</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="star_a" class="starRadio star-5" id="star_a-5" value="5"/>
    <label class="star-5" for="star_a-5">5</label>
    
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="stars">
    <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="starRadio star-1" id="star_b-1" value="1"/>
    <label class="star-1" for="star_b-1">1</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="starRadio star-2" id="star_b-2" value="2"/>
    <label class="star-2" for="star_b-2">2</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="starRadio star-3" id="star_b-3" value="3"/>
    <label class="star-3" for="star_b-3">3</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="starRadio star-4" id="star_b-4" value="4"/>
    <label class="star-4" for="star_b-4">4</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="star_b" class="starRadio star-5" id="star_b-5" value="5"/>
    <label class="star-5" for="star_b-5">5</label>
    
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, Im new to the concept of HTML. How do I implement the JS part onto a notepad ? do i start off with <script>...</script> ?

Comment: Yes that is one way to do it or you can make a new file and links to it on your html file `script.js` <- here lies the JS code, then on your html file: before the `</body>` tag add `<script src="script.js"></script>`  and I edited the answer  a little bit by wrapping it on a jQuery ready statement

Comment: So i just paste the JS code directly onto a notepad(Later renamed to script.js) without anything else?
which i refer to before </body>. I have edited my main post with the code in using, could you please check it out?

Comment: Note quite, to simplify things add the code to your notepad like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/qy8op3vz/

Comment: Usage of <form>..</form> is causing me a hindrance>

Comment: I got it working now, Made a silly mistake in the order of closing </script> after </body>. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: There's an error in your HTML that you need to change to make this code work. Make sure the `value`s are *not right next to the closing backslash* (`/`). For example, change this line:

```
<input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-2" id="star_a-2" value=2/>
                                                          change this ^
```

To this:

```
<input type="radio" name="star_a" class="star-2" id="star_a-2" value=2 />
                                                               to this ^
```

---

You can have a JavaScript / jQuery script that runs `onchange` of the radio buttons, like so:

```
$("input").change(function() {
    if($("input[name=star_a]").val() == "1" && $("input[name=star_b]").val() == "1") {
        var sum = parseInt($("input[name=star_a]:checked").val()) + parseInt($("input[name=star_b]:checked").val());
        alert(sum);
        $("#sum").text(sum);
    }
});
```

See a working example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywjw1a7p/1/).

Comment: Im new to JavaScript. Thank you for replying. I need to basically make a feedback form based on ratings. So i have n-rating classes which i need to find the average of -using the class stated above- and output the answer onto a text box or the same type of class. @Jonathan

Comment: If you look at the JSFiddle it outputs the sum into a `<span>`, and it's saved in a JS variable that you can use.

Comment: Its working perfectly fine on JSFiddle. But if I execute it on my browser, nothing seems to happen. Im really confused.

Comment: @VishnuRahul It might because I had to change your HTML a little in the JSfiddle to make it work. Make sure your `value`s are *not right next to the backslash* (`/`). I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I edited my main post. could you please check it out.

Comment: @VishnuRahul The only other thing I can think of is that you didn't include the jQuery library correctly. Have you used jQuery before? Do you know how to use it?

Comment: I got it working now, Made a silly mistake in the order of closing </script> after </body>. Thank you so much.